# How can I download all the emails from gmail acount to my local machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jruby

I am newbie on ruby on rails and gems...If any one help me to figure out that any gems or script that downloads all the emails from gmail to my local machine

I heard about `ruby 'net/imap'`

but using it I am not able  to fetch or authenticate

```
imap = Net::IMAP.new('mail.google.com')
imap.authenticate('LOGIN', 'bmonal125', 'aaaa')
```

Please suggest me ...

I need any kind of technical suggestion to overcome it

Thanks in advance

Comment: did you search in google ?

Comment: yes I had searched but no help...........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at http://rubydoc.info/gems/gmail, there are detailed examples on how to authenticate and retrieve messages.

If the authentication does not work, it is quite possible that your IMAP access is not configured in gmail. Have a look at support.google.com/mail/troubleshooter/1668960?hl=en#ts=1665018 on how to enable it

Comment: If the authentication does not work, it is quite possible that your IMAP access is not configured in gmail. Have a look at https://support.google.com/mail/troubleshooter/1668960?hl=en#ts=1665018 on how to enable it.

Comment: it is working thank you...please update your post I will accept it...thanks